# Select records of multiple pages using data-tables

Tags: jquery, datatables, angular-datatables

Have requirement like, I need to select records in datatables with different pages like first page 2 records, second page 3 records... I can able to select only first page, if I change to second page and select records, previously selected records are resetting and updating fresh data. I tried below code, please help if any issue on this..

```
  $("#firstTable input:checked").each(function() {
    if (info.index != "") {
      creditAmount += parseInt($(this).prop("value"));
    }
  });
  $("#idCheckBoxLabel").text(creditAmount);
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-edw9zj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

To process all rows in your DataTable, taking pagination into account, you cannot use the DOM and a jQuery selector. The only values visible in the DOM will be those in the currently displayed page - as you have seen.

Instead, you have to access your table's data via the DataTables API. This will give you access to the entire set of data stored in your DataTable, regardless of whether it is on the current page (and also, it can take filtering into account).

Here is my "minimal reproducible example" demo table, using your data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
      url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json",
    },
    columns: [
      { title: "", defaultContent: '<input type="checkbox" />' },
      { title: "Amount", data: "id" },
      { title: "First Name", data: "firstName" },
      { title: "Last Name", data: "lastName" }
    ]
  } );

} );
```

And then I define a function as follows:

```
function doSum() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var checkboxNodes = table.column(0).nodes();
  var amountData = table.column(1).data();
  
  var sum = 0;
    
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxNodes.length; i++) {
    if( $(checkboxNodes[i]).find("input").is(':checked') ) {
      sum += amountData[i];
    }
  }
  
  console.log(sum);
}
```

This function is attached to a button, for testing:

```
<button onclick="doSum()">Test</button>
```

The key parts here are the DataTables API calls:

```
table.column(0).nodes()
```

and

```
table.column(1).data()
```

Using each node, I can then use a jQuery selector to access the state of each checkbox - and get the related amount for the sum.